# object reference not set to an instance of an object when using parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oracle, nullreferenceexception

Can someone tell me how i can set the object reference to an instance? ....
Here, user_id is the parameter which takes a textbox value into the sql statement.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=KBETEST; Persist Security Info=TRUE; User ID=dbo; Password=dbo123; Unicode=True");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OracleDataAdapter adap = new OracleDataAdapter();
    OracleCommandBuilder b = new OracleCommandBuilder(adap);

    adap = new OracleDataAdapter("insert into banks_ben_branch_99 (ben_bank_id, ben_brn_code, brn_name,ben_brn_addr1, ben_brn_loc, ben_brn_state, ben_brn_city, ben_bank_city, coun_code,brn_stat, remarks, brn_id, user_id, pc_tcp_ip, rtgs_stat, pay_brn_code,sys_date) select bankid,benbrn_code,brn_name,substr(brn_addr,1,100),brn_loc, brn_stat, brn_city, brn_city, coun_code,'A', remarks, '15', :user_id,'172.20.1.109', rtgs_stat, benbrn_code,sysdate from bbbt",con);
    adap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("user_id", OracleType.VarChar,20, "user_id").Value = textBox1.Text;
    adap.Fill(ds,"A");
    DataTable table = ds.Tables["A"];
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["A"];
    con.Dispose();
}
```

thanks!

**edit**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=KBETEST; Persist Security Info=TRUE; User ID=dbo; Password=dbo123; Unicode=True");
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       OracleDataAdapter adap = new OracleDataAdapter();
       OracleCommandBuilder b = new OracleCommandBuilder(adap);
       string str = "insert into banks_ben_branch_99 (ben_bank_id, ben_brn_code, brn_name,ben_brn_addr1, ben_brn_loc, ben_brn_state, ben_brn_city, ben_bank_city, coun_code,brn_stat, remarks, brn_id, user_id, pc_tcp_ip, rtgs_stat, pay_brn_code,sys_date) select bankid,benbrn_code,brn_name,substr(brn_addr,1,100),brn_loc, brn_stat, brn_city, brn_city, coun_code,'A', remarks, '15', :user_id, '172.20.1.109', rtgs_stat, benbrn_code,sysdate from bbbt";
       con.Open();
       adap.InsertCommand = new OracleCommand(str, con);
       adap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("user_id", OracleType.VarChar,20).Value = textBox1.Text;
       adap.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

       con.Dispose();
        }
```

thanks everyone for your help!! i got it!

Comment: try using adap.Parameters.AddWithValue(":userv", textBox1.Text);

Comment: @Sasidharan still gave the error

Comment: make sure your parameters and database columns are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `adap.InsertCommand` is null in the following line:

```
adap.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add
```

On the previous line you use the following constructor:

```
adap = new OracleDataAdapter("insert into ...", con);
```

but this constructor initializes the `SelectCommand`, not the `InsertCommand`.  Therefore `adap.InsertCommand` will still have its default value, null.

Your code then goes on to attempt to fill a DataTable using this adapter:

```
adap.Fill(ds,"A");
```

but this won't work either: you need a `SelectCommand` to do this.

To fill a DataSet, your code should probably look something like:

```
adap = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...", con); 
adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(... any parameters you need ...);
adap.Fill(ds, "A");
```

> it is passing the break point now, no changes has been made to the oracle database tables! why is this happening.

I think you're misunderstanding how DataAdapters work.

To get data from the database into your DataTable, you need to:

- Create an adapter with a SelectCommand
- Call adapter.Fill to execute the SelectCommand and fill the DataTable with the result

To insert data into the database from your DataTable, you need to:

- Insert a row into your DataTable with the data you want to insert
- Create an adapter with an InsertCommand
- Call adapter.Update to insert the data into the database.

Updating / Deleting rows in the database is similar to inserting, but uses UpdateCommand and DeleteCommand.

Comment: it is passing the break point now. but no changes has been made to the oracle database tables! why is this happening?

Comment: @joe.. i forgot to execute non query. its working now. thank you for explaining in detail. helps :)

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: There are multiple things wrong with your code:

- You're not specifying the `user_id` parameter in the command, although it's in the SQL
- You're trying to use the `InsertCommand` of the adapter even though you haven't specified any insertion SQL
- You're trying to fill a dataset, but you haven't specified a query - just an insert command.

I suspect you shouldn't be using a data adapter at all. If you just need to insert some data, use:

```
using (var connection = new OracleConnection(...)
{
    connection.Open();
    string sql = "insert into banks_ben_branch_99 [... as before ...]";
    using (var command = new OracleCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("user_id", OracleType.VarChar, 20)
                          .Value = textBox1.Text;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: i edited the code like you said. i am still getting the error. and textBox1 is not null at this point. what could the problem be? must be something silly but i can put my finger on it.. please help..

Comment: @ShilpaGeorge: See my edit. Basically your whole approach of using a data adapter seems odd here.

Comment: @skeet i got it. failed to update the code earlier. thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

I think `user_id` is not a nullable column and it occurs when your parameter is empty. First thing is, parameter name does not match. After that, it still can happen when textbox is empty. It is better to check on client side for validation.

Comment: you are right. user_id is a not null column. but i am entering value in a textbox which should pass as parameter. and i matched the parameter names..

Answer (score 1):

The parameter that you have given is null.